# Get clicked-on character in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

I'm trying to write a chrome extension that makes a simple pop-up when you (for example) ctrl+click a character (it's a simple tool for helping to remember keywords for Japanese Kanji).

This is what I've got for an attempt so far - the `alert()` is just a placeholder to quickly show me what I've seen:

```js
document.addEventListener("click", (event) => {
    if (event.ctrlKey) {
        let selection = document.getSelection();
        if (selection.rangeCount == 1) {
            let letter = selection.focusNode.data[selection.focusOffset];

            alert(letter);
        }
    }
});
```

This *sometimes* gets the right character - e.g. on [this article](https://www3.nhk.or.jp/news/easy/k10014365121000/k10014365121000.html), at the start of the article (the orange characters, `石川県...`), it'll get the first two (`石` and `川`) correct, but display `undefined` for the third (i.e. should be `県`). Here's a snippet:

```js
document.addEventListener("click", (event) => {
    if (event.ctrlKey) {
        let selection = document.getSelection();
        if (selection.rangeCount == 1) {
            let letter = selection.focusNode.data[selection.focusOffset];
            console.log(letter);
        }
    }
});
```

```html
<p><span class="colorL"><ruby>石川県<rt>いしかわけん</rt></ruby><ruby>七尾市<rt>ななおし</rt></ruby></span><span class="colorB">で</span><span class="colorB">、</span><span class="color4"><ruby>先月<rt>せんげつ</rt></ruby></span><span class="colorB">の</span><span class="color3"><ruby>地震<rt>じしん</rt></ruby></span><span class="colorB">の</span><span class="color4">あと</span><span class="color1"><ruby><span class="under">避難</span><rt>ひなん</rt></ruby></span><span class="colorB">を</span><span class="color3"><ruby>続<rt>つづ</rt></ruby>け</span><span class="colorB">て</span><span class="color4">い</span><span class="colorB">る</span><span class="color4"><ruby>人<rt>ひと</rt></ruby></span><span class="colorB">の</span><span class="color3">ため</span><span class="colorB">に</span><span class="colorB">、</span><span class="colorC"><ruby>韓国大使館<rt>かんこくたいしかん</rt></ruby></span><span class="colorB">の</span><span class="color4"><ruby>人<rt>ひと</rt></ruby></span><span class="colorB">や</span><span class="colorL"><ruby>日本<rt>にっぽん</rt></ruby></span><span class="colorB">に</span><span class="color4"><ruby>住<rt>す</rt></ruby>ん</span><span class="colorB">で</span><span class="color4">いる</span><span class="color4"><ruby>韓国人<rt>かんこくじん</rt></ruby></span><span class="colorB">などが</span><span class="color4"><ruby>料理<rt>りょうり</rt></ruby></span><span class="colorB">を</span><span class="color4"><ruby>作<rt>つく</rt></ruby>り</span><span class="colorB">ました</span><span class="colorB">。</span></p>
```

If I log the values, I can see that the index I'm using (`selection.focusOffset`) is simply out of bounds for the data (`selection.focusNode.data`) that it's got. I can see there are three other `*offset`/`*Node.data` pairs, but they seem to all contain the same information so I've no idea which one would be the "right" one or when they would be different.

How can I reliably get the character that's been clicked on?

Comment: It looks like if you click on the _right_ half of a character `focusOffset`  (and `anchorOffset`) is the position _after_ the character, but if you click on the _left_ half of the character, it's the position _before_ the character. `getSelection` returns the [caret position](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getSelection) if you have no highlighted text, i.e. where the next character would be inserted if you started typing.

Comment: I was wondering about multi-code-unit characters and such, but that doesn't seem to be it. Like @Gaberocksall above, I'm seeing a different index depending on whether I'm on the left or right half of the character, which seems like a bug. But I get the same behavior on both a Chromium browser and Firefox, which argues that it *isn't* a bug. Weird.

Comment: I was also hoping using `anchorNode` (where the selection starts) instead of `focusNode` (where it ends) would help, but nope.

Comment: You may need to do some pixel math to try and determine whether you clicked on the left or right side of a character, but it would be MUCH easier to change the input method. For example, you hold CTRL and highlight the character (rather than just clicking on it). You _could_ convert every character on the page into a clickable `<span>`, but proceed with caution.

Comment: @Gaberocksall that sounds interesting - I'm a total noob at this, can you give a bit more detail? e.g. what actual event would I listen to, and do you know what sort of functions I should be looking at to get the selected text?

Comment: @JohnGraham You can get the highlighted text via simply `document.getSelection().toString()` in the same `click` event. The pixel math would be extremely complicated and delicate - I wouldn't recommend trying that. The span idea would involve iterating through the entire DOM and wrapping every character in `<span></span>` tags, then listening for clicks on every span (huge performance issue). It may be possible to wrap characters in spans only after clicking on a text node, and check the `hover` status to figure out which character you're hovering over (a.k.a. the one you just clicked on).

Answer (score 0):

I went with a suggestion from @Gaberocksall, which involved changing the input method. Now I get all the selected text and, if it's ctrl+clicked-on, see the alert:

```
document.addEventListener("click", (event) => {
    if (event.ctrlKey) {
        let selection = document.getSelection().toString();

        if (selection.length == 1) {
            alert(selection);
        }
    }
});
```

(N.B. I found you could highlight hyperlink text by holding the Alt key, which is useful here too, and this solution will do for me as it's a hacky self-project only at this stage)

Answer (score -2):

selection.focusOffset might be pointing to the wrong index within the string. One potential solution is to get the character directly from the clicked element's text content rather than relying on the selection API.

```
document.addEventListener("click", (event) => {
    if (event.ctrlKey) {
        let targetElement = event.target;
        if (targetElement.nodeType === Node.TEXT_NODE) {
            let letter = targetElement.textContent.trim();
            if (letter.length === 1) {
                alert(letter);
            }
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: Most text nodes will not be a single character long.

Comment: This doesn't seem to work - the nodes always seem to come up as the `Element` type [from here](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_node_nodetype.asp) and the text content when I click in a word (e.g. first part of the article as indicated in original post) is, as @Gaberocksall says, not a character, but includes a bunch of them.